# mount JFFS2 resulted with returned ECC error

Tags: linux, flash, mount, openwrt, jffs2

I'm trying to mount 1[MB] Flash partition on my linux machine.
I'm using the following command -

```
mount -t jffs2 -o noatime /dev/mtdblock6 /NVM
```

Where mtdblock6 is the mtd block I want to mount, and /NVM is the folder.
This action results with the following error

```
jffs2: mtd->read(0x100 bytes from 0xc0000) returned ECC error
```

Can anyone suggest why is this happening?

Thank you all in advanced!

Comment: Without even searching, I would assume that your partition/disk has errors.

Comment: Non that I could see, but maybe I need to format it before mounting?

Comment: Ummm... is the partition even formated, then?

Comment: It does, but immediately begins to print ECC errors. I will try to format it before mounting and update you on the results.

Comment: Yep, that's seems to solve this. So the solution if anyone is intresting is to add format command before mounting

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mounting on Linux. Should probably be migrated to Unix & Linux SE site.

Comment: Hו  @user2568434, Did you solve this issue ? Can you add your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
The described issue was caused due to wrong initialization of our NAND flash.
JFFS2 uses flash spare area to encode file system data, but in our NAND initialization we deleted this section. The result was the issue described above.

We bypassed it by erasing 'clean marker' at boot, and then jffs thinks he needs to re-initialize the block - then no issue observers.